# Why is the ground state energy of a 2DEG higher compared to the 3DEG?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, schroedinger-equation, potential, spacetime-dimensions

I am reading something about a 2DEG (2-dimensional electrongas model) and can not understand it.
My book says the ground state of the 2DEG is higher compared to a 3DEG because the confinement to 2D increases the energy (the book calls this ***confinement energy*** but I can not finde stuff about it online - only quark stuff pops up).

Both systems (3D and 2D) seem to have similar energies (or energy eigenvalues) which are of the usual form: $E \sim \frac{\hbar^2\pi^2n^2}{2mL^2}$ but it seems like that for some reason in the 3DEG n can be zero but in the 2DEG it can not an starts at 1. The system as hight of $L$ in the $z$ direction and in that direction the confinement takes place.
The energy difference of the two ground states seems to be: $\frac{\hbar^2\pi^2}{2mL^2}$.

The Model seems to suggest that in the $xy$-plane the particles act a like free particle but an infinite plane with $z$ confinement seems pretty weird to me.
Perhaps the $z$-length is way smaller than the $x$- and $y$-length in typical 2DEG Models and thus we approximate it?
But even if that would be the case - how would one compare the energy of a free particle (which does not have a definite energy as far as I understand it) with the energy of a particle in a infinite well?

Edit:
The potential has the form:

$$V(z) = 0 ; \text{for} - \frac{L}{2} ≤ z ≤  \frac{L}{2}$$

$$V(z) = ∞ ; \text{else}$$

Edit:
It would make sense if a free electron can have zero $k$-Vector and thus zero energy but wouldn`t that mean it does not exist in the first place? 
It would also work if $L$ is really really small such that the energy-term due to the infinite-well is much much bigger than the free kinetic energy term.

Comment: please be specific. you mean if they have same number of electrons, and same density per volumn or per area? Do they have pairwise interaction?

Comment: When you say *ground state* are you asking about the lowest energy level (populated by just two electrons) or the lowest energy state for the whole system i.e. the Fermi energy?

Comment: I mean the groundstate of one electron and in this model (free electrongas) there is no interaction between the electrons.

Comment: I guess we can at first just look at one electron and compare its groundstate if it moves in 3D / 2D.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which book? Which pages?

Comment: It is a german book called "Festkörperphysik" (engl. solid-state-physics) by Rudolf Gross, Adolf Marx.

Comment: i think you may talking about hydrogen atom in 2D and 3D

Comment: Hydrogen has a different potential: V ~ 1/r

Comment: Just to clarify: are you asking about 2DEGs as in semiconductor heterostructures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easiest if you consider a rectangular box in 3D, with length $L_x$ in the $x-y$ plane, and length $L_z \ll L_x$ in the $z$ direction. Now, $L_x$ is very large, and you are only interested in the physics deep within the bulk, far from the boundaries. Therefore it is of little importance exactly which boundary conditions you choose. It is often easier to choose periodic boundary conditions in the $x$ and $y$ directions. (This gives identical predictions to box boundary conditions for almost all quantities in the limit $L_x\to 0$.)

The energy eigenstates for a single electron are then of the form
$$ \psi(\mathbf{r}) \sim e^{i2\pi(n_x x + n_y y)/L_x}\sin(\pi n_z z/L_z). $$
up to an uninteresting normalisation factor. The quantum numbers defining the momentum are $n_x,n_y = 0,1,2,3,\ldots$ and $n_z = 1,2,3,\ldots$. Notice that it is possible to have $n_x = 0$ or $n_y = 0$. There is nothing odd about this, it simply means that the electron has zero momentum in these directions, so that its wave function is constant. However, $n_z = 0$ is not a meaningful solution, since this means that the entire wave function vanishes.

The energies are given by
$$ E(n_x,n_y,n_z) = \frac{1}{2m}\left[ \left(\frac{2\pi \hbar n_x}{L_x}\right)^2 +   \left(\frac{2\pi \hbar n_y}{L_x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\pi \hbar n_z}{L_z}\right)^2  \right].$$

The energy of the single-particle ground state is just $E(0,0,1)$. Obviously this is larger for small $L_z$. Fundamentally this is a consequence of the Heisenberg uncertainty principle. Since the position of the electrons is sharply localised in the $z$ direction, the momentum in the $z$ direction has very large fluctuations. These fluctuations give rise to a large kinetic energy, which is the "confinement energy" referred to in your book.

In a (real) 2D system, the electrons are so tightly confined in the $z$ direction that every single one has $n_z = 1$. This requires that the temperature be very low, so that there is not enough thermal energy to excite electrons to higher motional states in the $z$ direction. Explicitly, the thermal energy must be smaller than the gap to the first excited state in the $z$ direction, which is $$E(n_x,n_y, 2) - E(n_x,n_y,1) = \frac{3\pi^2\hbar^2}{2mL_z^2}.$$ So as long as $k_B T \ll \hbar^2/(mL_z^2)$ then the motion in the $z$ direction is frozen out, so the system is effectively 2D.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I came up with some rough ideas but you wrote it pretty clearly and now I think I do understand it in precise way.